# Mockito, Verify one of the method call among several

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing a Junit test with mockito and I want to verify a method call is made. Problem is there are multiple method calls made with different parameters and I want to verify only one of those .

```
Eg : Below are 3 method calls from my code
Metrics.emit(PhoneFailCount,0);
Metrics.emit(PaymentFailCount,1);
Metrics.emit(AddresseFailCount,1);
```

How do I verify that

`Metrics.emit(PaymentFailCount,1)` is called atleast once.

If I directly do 
`verify(Metrics).emit(PaymentFailCount, 1)` 
it throws error saying Argument(s) are different! because its trying to match with Metrics.emit(PhoneFailCount,0)

I tried using ArgumentCaptor but is not possible to capture both parameters at once

Thanks

Comment: What is `PhoneFailCount`, etc? Normally, variables are written in camelCase, starting with a lower case character. Not adhering to such standards makes it hard to understand your code - especially as you give no context.

Comment: what do you meant by "but is not possible to capture both parameters at once". It is possible to do this with ArgumentCaptor. Put your code where you tried with ArgumentCaptor, may be we can help

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz its a variable. Ill keep your suggestion in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use ArgumentCaptor for this purpose. Chec this code below. This should work

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> captor1 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

ArgumentCaptor<Integer> captor2 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);

verify(Metrics, times(3)).emit(captor1.capture(), captor2.capture);

List<Integer> values = captor2.getAllValues;
//assertIf values have values 0,1 and 1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply

I dont think this works because you are asserting captor1 has "PaymentFailCount" and captor2 has "1" which is not always correct as Captor2 might get value 1 from AddresseFailCount also.

Comment: It doesn't matter captor will collect all arguments from all calls. Did you try ?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to argument captors is using hamcrest matchers in `Mockito.verify()`, but you have to set rules to match against while verifying:

`verify(Metrics, times(1)).emit(eq(PaymentFailCount),eq(1));`

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
Metrics metrics = mock(Metrics.class);

// run code that uses metrics

verify(metrics, times(3)).emit(any(), anyInt());
verify(metrics).emit(PaymentFailCount, 1);
```

All the static imports come from `org.mockito.Mockito.*`.

Note: This way doesn't preserve order of invocation, means if you reorder the `emit` calls the test will still pass.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but for just the record: With the current mockito version, you can write just that:

```
verify(Metrics, atLeastOnce()).emit(PaymentFailCount, 1);
```